# Why does glob('*[jp][pn]g') work but glob('*p[ng][df]') does not? (Syntax of glob with [])

Tags: python, glob

```
from glob import glob

somefiles = glob(f'{samples_dir}/*p[ng][df]')
```

Returns an empty list.

But this one returns all my png and jpg files.  The folder contains png, jpg, and pdf files.

```
otherfiles = glob(f'{samples_dir}/*[jp][pn]g')
```

I'm just curious as to why the first one doesn't work. Clearly I don't fully understand the `[]` syntax of python3's `glob` method.

Comment: How do you *think* "the `[]` syntax" works?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](//docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)? *"... **character ranges** expressed with `[]` ... `'[?]'` matches the character `'?'`"* and there's an example at the bottom that uses `'[0-9]'`. You can also look up the *"rules used by the Unix shell"* e.g. [on Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax): *"`[abc]` : matches one character given in the bracket"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `[...]` expression matches any single one of the characters contained between the braces. So:

- `[jp][pn]g` would match "foo.jpg", "foo.jng", "foo.ppg", and "foo.png".
- `p[ng][df]` would match "foo.pnd", "foo.pnf", "foo.pgd", and "foo.pgf"

Most of the results for the second expression don't seem all that useful.

For what you're doing, I would probably write something like:

```
somefiles = (
  glob(f'{samples_dir}/*.png') +
  glob(f'{samples_dir}/*.jpg') +
  glob(f'{samples_dir}/*.pdf')
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the docs make more sense...I read them 3 times and it just wasn't clicking; I did ultimately do it the way you proposed but now I understand how the syntax actually works and why what I thought should work wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

According to [[Python.Docs]: fnmatch - Unix filename pattern matching](https://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) (used by *glob*):

> `[seq]` - matches any character in *seq*

So, the patterns expand to (starting each group from left to right - a bit unnatural, but (hopefully) clearer):

```
                      jpg
                    /
             j[pn]g 
           /        \
          /           jng
[jp][pn]g
          \           ppg
           \        /
             p[pn]g
                    \
                      png
```

and

```
                      pnd
                    /
             pn[df]
           /        \
          /           pnf
p[ng][df]
          \           pgd
           \        /
             pg[df]
                    \
                      pgf
```

So the 1<sup>st</sup> pattern "catches" *.jpg* and *.png* files (and 2 other unmatched), while the 2<sup>nd</sup> catches 4 unmatched variants.

To catch *.png* and *.pdf* files (got that from your pattern that doesn't work), you might want to use ***p[nd][gf]***: expanding it, will reveal that it catches them (+ unmatched *.pnf* and *.pdg*).

Comment: Thank you!  This explanation is very helpful.  What the docs say now seems more obvious...for some reason I wasn't seeing it this way.